# How to post a video to the Thingworx platform

Tags: thingworx

I have a short video (about 6 seconds) and I want to post it to a service in Thingworx, where the service has a parameter of type Blob. I tried to post the Video using Postman client but I always have a 403 error; where the request is legal but the server refuses to respond to it. Could you help me please finding the right way to upload the video files?

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ9bs.png)

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDT13.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hggga.png)

Comment: Do you get anything in the Applicationlog or Scriptlog?

Comment: actually, I didn't. I walk around this by sending the video as Base64 string, but couldn't send it as binary